# MuleSoft - use decryption with null paylod

Tags: mule

I'm trying to use MuleSoft's decryption on HTTP requests. I'm doing this also on GET requests.

I get the following error:

> ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ERROR 2015-05-17 13:00:35,630
>   [[broker1-secure].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01]
>   org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
>   ******************************************************************************** Message               : Failed to invoke decrypt. Message payload is
>   of type: NullPayload Code                  : MULE_ERROR-29999
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Exception stack is:
>   1. Could not decrypt the input. The input has to be a byte array,Input Stream or String (java.lang.RuntimeException)
>   org.mule.modules.security.encryption.encrypters.JCEEncrypterModule:59
>   (null)
>   2. Failed to invoke decrypt. Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
>   org.mule.devkit.processor.DevkitBasedMessageProcessor:128
>   (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Root Exception stack trace: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not
>   decrypt the input. The input has to be a byte array,Input Stream or
>   String    at
>   org.mule.modules.security.encryption.encrypters.JCEEncrypterModule.decrypt(JCEEncrypterModule.java:59)
>     at
>   org.mule.modules.security.encryption.EncryptionModule.decrypt(EncryptionModule.java:213)
>     at
>   org.mule.modules.security.encryption.processors.DecryptMessageProcessor$1.process(DecryptMessageProcessor.java:165)
>       + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)

Shouldn't it be possible? Try to decrypt payload, and if nothing to decrypt then continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to only decrypt if the payload is not null: it's better to avoid raising exceptions if you can.

For this, you can use a choice router to decrypt only if the payload is not null.